# Формат времени на PHP

Tags: php, mysql, дата, время, формат

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код следующего вида:

```
<small>' ,$topic['description'],'</small>
```

В БД description содержит дату и время в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД ЧЧ:ММ:СС.
Как изменить эту строку, чтобы на выходе дата была в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ ЧЧ:ММ? Спасибо!

Comment: Уберите, пожалуйста, mysql из тега и темы, он не очень имеет отношение к вопросу, по крайней мере в данной постановке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот три варианта.
Первый:

```
echo date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime('2017-01-01 15:15:15'));
```

Второй:

```
$a = new DateTime('2017-01-01 15:15:15');
echo $a->format('d.m.Y H:i');
```

Если же у Вас в переменной содержится не только дата-время, но еще и какой-то текст, то как-то так:

```
$b = 'Торопыжка был голодный 2017-01-01 15:15:15 проглотил утюг холодный';

$c = preg_replace(
    '/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/',
    '$3.$2.$1 $4:$5',
    $b
);
echo $c;
```